Semantic versioning for a project of a collection of document classes?
I am planning to write some document classes for use in a company. So far, my idea is to write an article class based on scrartcl and respecting our CI/CD, and to write some specific classes for different use cases based on that article class, and then maybe expand the whole thing with a report class (based on scrrprt).
As far as I can see now, if I maintain a changelog, it will be for the entire project. Apart from that, there would be only one version number, which would be for the entire project. I have seen code or tutorials for LaTeX classes containing a file version and a file date:
\newcommand{\fileversion}{0.13.0}
\newcommand{\filedate}{2023/11/21}

To me, this looks like every file gets its own version number. That seems to contradict having a version number for the entire project.
What would be best practice when it comes to versioning such a LaTeX project (or maybe even any project consisting of several files, which is usually the case)?

Use one version number by class should be ok.

there is no best practice it is up to you. we tend to give each file its own version./date in combined bumdles such as latex-tools or ho-tex/oberdiek that contain several packages, but if you choose to make them all the same, that is fine too

In particular we mostly version the source files, so in the base latex release article, report and book class have the same version and date as they are generated from classes.dtx and the same version info is injected in to each.  Conversely other packages in base such as ifthen are generated from their own dtx and carry their own version number.

@DavidCarlisle: I didn't know you can generate more than one class from one dtx file. Sounds like that would be the way to go in my case. I still have to learn dtx. Is there a good ressource for that?

@ehak look at texdoc docstrip or simply look at the base latex release, article.cls report.cls and book.cls  are all generated from classes.dtx
